# How to add an image as attachement with SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, image, email

I am making an email client wpf app. Its working fine except that i don't know how to add an image to it.
I also want to save my composed email as pdf or docx file on PC.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a suitable answer.
Please Help

My email method is like:

```
 private void sendEmailB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(gmailID.Text, gmailPass.Password);
        client.EnableSsl = true;




        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(gmailID.Text);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(sendEmailID.Text));
        msg.Subject = "handmail message";
        msg.Body = contentMain.Text;
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to send mail due to some reasons" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your question has nothing about WPF, removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding the image attachement, you can simple try this

```
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imagePath));
```

where *imagePath* contains the location(path) of the image that is going to be uploaded.

Comment: And how the user can select location of the image?

Comment: you are probably using `OpenFileDialog` control to select the image. If yes then you can fetch the path of that image.